# How to extract "Message" part from Google API error message

Tags: c#, google-api

I need to format exception messages returned from Google and present them in a nice way to end users.
(Using C#)

Format of the exception: (In this case I am calling Admin SDK.)

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError.Entity already exists.  [409].
>   Errors     [. 
>       Message[Entity already exists.] 
>       Location [ - ] 
>       Reason [duplicate] 
>       Domain [global]    .]

Another error,

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError.Domain user limit reached.  [412].
>   Errors     [. 
>        Message[Domain user limit reached.] 
>        Location [If-Match - header] 
>        Reason[limitExceeded] 
>        Domain[global]    .]

How can I extract "Message" from the above error messages?
("Entity already exists." or "Domain user limit reached." in above examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for Regix. The following should do what you need:

```
        string message1 = "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError.Entity already exists. "
                          +"[409]. Errors [. Message[Entity already exists.] Location [ - ] Reason [duplicate] Domain [global] .]";
        string message2 = "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError.Domain user limit reached. "
                          +"[412]. Errors [. Message[Domain user limit reached.] Location [If-Match - header] Reason[limitExceeded] Domain[global] .]";

        string pattern = @"Message\[((\w+\s){2,}(\w+\s?)*)\.\]";

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        Match m = regex.Match(message1); //or regex.Match(message2)
        if (m.Success)
        {
            Group g = m.Groups[1]; //m.Groups[0] will Match 'Message[.....]'
            CaptureCollection cc = g.Captures;

            for (int i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
            {
                Capture c = cc[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", c);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Got a small issue with this, "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError.Not Authorized to access this resource/api [403].Errors [. Message[Not Authorized to access this resource/api] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global].].";. This error returns empty as the "Message" (Not Authorized to access this resource/api) here does not have a full stop ".". Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try this patter.

> string pattern = @"Message[([A-Za-z0-9-\s*]+)]*";

Comment: This solved the issue with the messages that does not have "." in the message block.